# How to get simple metrics for code in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, metrics

I have just got the responsibility for around 100 different repositories (applications), distributed on about 20 project in Azure DevOps.

I want to get some (very) basic metrics on each project:

- Numbers and names of repositories in each project
- Number of branches in a repository
- Number of files in a branch
- Number of code lines in a branch
- Names of developers which has worked on a project
- Number of developers which has worked on a project
- First and last commit/pull request from a developer on a project
- etc.

Just simple counting and listing. Nothing fancy as test coverage etc. So far all my searching has only given results about code analysis and other advanced stuff. It's not where I am in my tasks right now.

Is there a way to do it in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure DevOps doesn’t directly provide a built-in feature to summarize the information you need. If you need a more automated way, consider using Azure DevOps REST API.

The following is an example PowerShell script using the [Azure DevOps Git API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to obtain the repositories and branch numbers:

```
# Define organization, PAT
$orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/orgname"
$pat = "xxx"
$APIVersion = "api-version=6.1-preview.1"

$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))
}

# Function to make REST API requests
function Invoke-AzureDevOpsAPI {
    param (
        [string]$url,
        [string]$method
    )
    try {
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Method $method
        return $response
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Error calling API: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        return $null
    }
}


# Get the list of all projects
$projectsUrl = "$orgUrl/_apis/projects?$APIVersion"
$projectsResponse = Invoke-AzureDevOpsAPI -url $projectsUrl -method "GET"

if ($projectsResponse) {
    Write-Host "Projects in your organization:"
    foreach ($project in $projectsResponse.value) {
        Write-Host "  $($project.name)"
        
        # Get repositories for the current project
        $reposUrl = "$orgUrl/$($project.name)/_apis/git/repositories?$APIVersion"
        $reposResponse = Invoke-AzureDevOpsAPI -url $reposUrl -method "GET"
        
        if ($reposResponse) {
            Write-Host "    Repositories in project:"
            foreach ($repo in $reposResponse.value) {
                Write-Host "      $($repo.name)"
                
                # Get branches for the current repository
                $branchesUrl = "$orgUrl/$($project.name)/_apis/git/repositories/$($repo.id)/refs?filter=heads&api-version=6.0"
                $branchesResponse = Invoke-AzureDevOpsAPI -url $branchesUrl -method "GET"
                
                if ($branchesResponse) {
                    $branchCount = $branchesResponse.count
                    Write-Host "        Number of branches: $branchCount"
                }
                else {
                    Write-Host "        Failed to retrieve branch information for $($repo.name)."
                }

            }
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "    Failed to retrieve repository information for $($project.name)."
        }
    }
}
else {
    Write-Host "Failed to retrieve project information."
}
```

For the developers information, you can try with this API [Commits - Get Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1&tabs=HTTP).

For the Number of Files in a Branch and Number of Code Lines in a Branch, it seems no API is related to it. You can clone the repository and run git command to get the information.

You can also check the [Azure DevOps extension Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=repo&target=AzureDevOps&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) to find the appropriate extension. If there is no extension that you are satisfied with, you can also [develop your own extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops).